# Angular.js application does not work on IIS but there's no errors in the console

Tags: angularjs, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to push my Angular.js SPA to an IIS7 server but having issues.  The application appears to load halfway (as my views and templates are loaded fine), but then stops functioning like so:

[image: Broken Angular SPA]

As you can see there is no errors in the console...and just for good measure I checked Fiddler which also is having no problems:

[image: Fiddler no issues]

The SPA works completely fine on my local web server and only seems to have issues when pushed to IIS.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Looks like the problem was with angular-csp.css not being properly included when running `grunt build` -- this was resolved by adding the following to my project's bower.json file:

```
"overrides": {
    "angular": {
      "main": [
        "angular.js",
        "angular-csp.css"
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a similar issue, but only when acessing the site externaly from another computer in the same network. I only see the html stuff. I could see that the angular.js script isn't loaded (inside the debugger). But the path src="angular.js" is correct, the other javascript files get loaded well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after coming at this with a fresh mind it appears you are correct--everything is working proplery--except my ng-show directives.

Obviously this is because angular-csp.css was not included when running "grunt build."

Since it's not in the angular bower.json main section, I needed to add the following to my projects bower.json:

```
"overrides": { "angular": { "main": ["angular.js", angular-csp.css"] } }
```

which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Mime Types on your IIS server? If IIS doesn't know about a particular file type it will often just ignore it.

Also check that you have *CORS* enabled if you are requesting data from a host other than the one you are deploying to.

Finally, check that you have correctly configured IIS to work with `HTML5mode` (if you have it enabled. See [How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Comment: I have verified the mime types on the server look good (was getting 404 on my TPL files before doing this).  As for CORS, I am requesting data from another site on the same server and have verified this is working properly.  I have not enabled HTML 5 mode (I still have a # in my URL) but I may give it a shot next to see if it makes any difference.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: What is the actual error? Chrome dev tools console or network panel must be showing an error our something failed to load?

Comment: No errors in either the console or network panel unfortunately.

Comment: So what is the problem then? If nothing is showing as error, and everything is loaded as expected, then it points to something wrong with your application. Without more info on what is going "wrong" it's very difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: Alright after coming at this with a fresh mind it appears you are correct--everything is working proplery--except my ng-show directives.  Obviously this is because angular-csp.css was not included when running "grunt build."  Since it's not in he angular bower.json main section, I needed to add the following to my projects bower.json: "overrides": { "angular": { "main": ["angular.js", angular-csp.css"] } } which fixed the problem.